# how to inline virtual with multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, c++11, inline, multiple-inheritance, type-traits

Please do not bash me or say that I am wrong for asking this question or that multiple inheritance is evil. This question is to get a better understanding of how C++ compliers work. I know that the `inline` statement is used to hint the compilier to replace a function call with source code the complier has every option with or not to inline the function. If you could force `inline` function that would be great but that is not really the issue I am trying to solve. What I want to do is to be able to create one piece of code that is written in one place and copying and pasted in other places by the complier. The code the I write would look something like this:

```
struct base 
{
    virtual double eval() = 0; // should be no eval function for the
};

struct foo : public base
{
    virtual double eval() overrides
    {
          return //foo eval
    }
};

struct bar : public base
{
    virtual double eval() overrides
    {
          return //foo eval
    }
};

struct baz : public base
{
    virtual double eval() overrides
    {
          return //baz eval
    }
};

struct FooBarBaz : public foo, public bar, public baz
{
    virtual double eval() final
    {
          return foo::eval() + bar::eval() + baz::eval();
    }
};
```

the complier would generate something that is equivalent to this:

```
struct base 
{
    virtual double eval() = 0; // should be no eval function for the
};

struct foo : public base
{
    virtual double eval() overrides
    {
          return //foo eval
    }
};

struct bar : public base
{
    virtual double eval() overrides
    {
          return //foo eval
    }
};

struct baz : public base
{
    virtual double eval() overrides
    {
          return //baz eval
    }
};

struct FooBarBaz : public foo, public bar, public baz
{
    virtual double eval() final
    {
          return /*foo eval*/ + /*bar eval*/ + /*baz eval*/
    }
};
```

I was told that using `<type_traits>` is the way to solve this problem if this is true I would like to know how to get the desired results. if not I would like to know how to do this

Comment: Do you know if the compiler is already performing what you want?  Have you tried setting the optimization levels and then looking at the assembly language listing?

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but how do you envision `inlined` code from working differently with multiple inheritance?

Comment: I am neutral on  the complier and done have a good understanding of assembler language. As for the `inline` code the complier would take the code from the use the code from the base function call and paste the code in the derived function instead of going through v-table to lookup the function

Comment: `foo::eval()`, `bar::eval()` and `baz::eval()` are not virtual calls anyway, AFAIK.

Comment: Since "code that is written in one place and copying and pasted in other places by the complier" is the *definition* of inlining it doesn't make sense for you to say that forcing inline "is not really the issue" when you want "code that is written in one place and copying and pasted in other places by the complier"

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19532791/3404097) help?

Comment: @philipxy: Not really. In the body of  `FooBarBaz` the compiler cannot know whether the object is of that type or anything derived from it, but that does not matter since the calls are qualified `foo::eval()`… and that disables dynamic dispatch.  The link you provide would be an answer to *when will the call to `eval()` (unqualified) be inlinable*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether the compiler decides to inline or not is up to the heuristics it has coded… but there is no reason why it shouldn't inline the calls to `foo::eval`, `bar::eval` and `baz::eval` from `FooBarBaz::eval` since the qualification disables dynamic dispatch.

That is, when the compiler encounters a qualified call `foo::eval`, it will execute the final overrider for that member function a the level of `foo`. It will not use the `vtable` (which would end up in infinite recursion anyways, since the final overrider would be `FooBarBaz::eval`.

Other than that, you should read about *virtual inheritance*, the `FooBarBaz` has **3** subobjects of type `base`, probably not what you want...

Comment: I like you answer however the `base` function is a pure abstract function only to provide a standard interface without any implementation or data to all the derived objects and therefore _virtual inheritance_ make no sense unless I would need the _virtual inheritance_ to allow the complier to the right thing.

Comment: @vickoza: `FooBarBaz fbz; base & b = fbz`. Error: ambiguous conversion as there are more than one `base`, which do you want to bind? *Empty* bases used as interfaces are the prime candidates for `virtual` inheritance: If there is a complete object and that happens to implement the same interface through different inheritance paths that's fine, there is just *one* object that implements the protocol.

Comment: Thank now I understand I thought that virtual inheritance merges the base implementation so you only have one base if you have many object the share the same base so are you saying the I sure define  `struct FooBarBaz : public virtual foo, public virtual bar, public virtual baz` if so than when using inheritance is it always a good idea to use virtual inheritance

Comment: @vickoza: I am not making myself clear, inheritance from `base` should be virtual (pure interface). Making the other inheritance relationships `virtual` won't help you, since as you mentioned it only helps in *merging* inheritance in different paths from the same base. It is **not** always a good idea to have virtual inheritance, and it comes with a cost in many scenarios (the layout of the object is not fixed)